# How to combine 2 vectors in a particular order?

Tags: r, vector

I have the following variables:

```
loc.dir <- c(1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1)
max.index <- c(40, 46, 56, 71, 96, 113, 156)
min.index <- c(38, 48, 54, 69, 98, 112, 155)
```

My goal is to produce the following:

```
data.loc <- c(40, 48, 56, 69, 96, 112, 156)
```

In words, I look at each element `loc.dir`. If the ith element is 1, then I will take the ith element in `max.index`. On the other hand, if the ith element is -1, then I will take the ith element in `min.index`.

I am able to get the elements that should be in `data.loc` by using:

```
plus.1 <- max.index[which(loc.dir == 1)]
minus.1 <- min.index[which(loc.dir == -1)]
```

But now I don't know how to combine `plus.1` and `minus.1` so that it is identical to `data.loc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifelse` was designed for this:

```
ifelse(loc.dir == 1, max.index, min.index)
#[1]  40  48  56  69  96 112 156
```

It does something similar to this:

```
res <- min.index
res[loc.dir == 1] <- max.index[loc.dir == 1]
```